# Rails server on AWS hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

I have hosted a rails application on AWS. Every time I want to access my website, I have to go through some steps which are quite repetitive.

```
1. ssh -i <<a>my-keypair-pem> ec2-user@<<a>AWS-IPv4-public-IP>
2. rails s -p <<a>port> -b 0.0.0.0
```

After some time, I also get this error

> 'packet_write_wait: Connection to <AWS-IPv4-public-IP> port 22: Broken pipe'

I did some research and can't seem to find a way to keep my application running 24/7 without having to do these steps before accessing every time.
My AWS instance is on 24/7, so the website should run 24/7 as well.

Would assign an elastic IP to my instance help?

Appreciate any guidance.

**EDIT**: I followed this tutorial initially https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFBbcleSPoY and that is where I found the steps mentioned above.

Comment: This issue might not be related to rails at all. See this https://serverfault.com/questions/811277/packet-write-wait-broken-pipe-error-on-macos-sierra-ssh-to-amazon-ec2 . Also look through the settings mentioned in question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118198/trouble-connecting-to-rails-server-in-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with https://mosh.org/, for anyone who stumbles on this post in the future.

Download and install mosh (mobile shell) 
Run the modified version of the command mentioned in my original question

`mosh -ssh="ssh -i <your-keypair.pem>" ec2-user@<AWS-Instance-IP>`

This resolved my packet_write_wait issues and I don't have to keep restarting the rails server.

Comment: Your website will go away if AWS ever recycle that EC2 instance (which happens more often than you might believe).

Comment: What do you mean by recycle? and what's the solution to avoid such a situation?

Comment: As in, EC2s are ephemeral.  They can go down at any time if there is an underlying hardware issue, or if amazon decide they need to perform maintenance.  The way to host a service is to load-balance it across two or more EC2s in at least two availability zones.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to run the rails server as daemon. If you google for "rails server as daemon", you will see many links. Have not added any links as many of good links are by hosting service providers.

If you still want to run the rails server through the shell for some reason, `tmux` is the way to go. The following excerpt is shamelessly copied from `Tmux` Wiki.

***tmux is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal.***

You can open a `tmux` terminal and start rails server. You can detach from the `tmux` and quit your ssh session. Whenever you wish, you can ssh back to your server and re-attach to the `tmux` session. You rails server will still be running as you left it. This is great way to run development server in foreground for debugging.